# MySQL JOIN+COUNT+WHERE+AND

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have table of regions:

```
table region: 
id | title
```

Region has many adverts:

```
table advert:
id | region_id | ...
```

Then advert has many uses (many-many through table adv_use):

```
table use:
use | slug   | ...
----------------
1   | slug_1 | ...
2   | slug_2 | ...
..................



table adv_use:
adv_id | use_id
```

I want select all regions with count(*) of adverts, which have uses with slug_1 AND slug_2. If advert has no use with slug_1 or with slug_2 (or both), it's must not be counted.
What i have now:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT advert.id) as count
FROM region
JOIN advert ON region.id = advert.region_id
JOIN adv_use ON advert.id = adv_use.adv_id
JOIN use ON adv_use.use_id = use.id
WHERE use.slug IN ('slug_1', 'slug_2')
GROUP BY region.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT adv_use.use_id) = 2
```

But it's working not as i want.
SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b4d4/1

Thanks for help and sorry for bad english.

Comment: You can't count `advert.id` if you also have `advert.id` in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: If i remove it from  GROUP BY, it's still works wrong. It's ignors HAVING statement and counts only by  use.slug IN ('slug_1', 'slug_2')

Comment: SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b4d4/1

Comment: +1 for a properly asked question. A bit too localized, maybe, but at least it respects the guidelines.

Comment: It looks right to me. Region 1 has advert 1, which uses slug1 and slug2. Region 2 has adverts 2 and 3; advert 2 uses slug1 and slug2, advert 3 uses slug2. So these two regions are in the results.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. The count for region 2 should just be 1, because you don't want to count advert 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a subquery to select the `adv_id` that use both slugs:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT advert.id) as count, region.id as reg_id
FROM region
JOIN advert ON region.id = advert.region_id
JOIN (SELECT adv_use.adv_id
      FROM adv_use
      JOIN tbl_use ON adv_use.use_id = tbl_use.id
      WHERE tbl_use.slug IN ('slug1', 'slug2')
      GROUP BY adv_use.adv_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT adv_use.use_id) = 2) adv_use
ON advert.id = adv_use.adv_id
GROUP BY region.id
;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b4d4/12)